# Linking a django docker container to a mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

As I am fairly new to this, I read a decent amount on the Internet before I started and I think I did everything as it was said in the tutorials, however, my django application does not want to use the mysql container. From what I have read, in the `settings.py` file I have to add the following code:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'TheDatabase',
    'USER': 'TheUsername',
    'PASSWORD': 'ThePassword',
    'HOST': 'mysql',
    'PORT': '3306',

    }
}
```

I am using a `docker-compose.yml` to link both docker containers and my `docker-compose.yml` looks as follow:

```
version: '2'
services:
    mysql:  
        image: mysql:latest
        environment:
            -MYSQL_DATABASE: TheDatabase
            -MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
            -MYSQL_USER: TheUsername
            -MYSQL_PASSWORD: ThePassword

    django:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - "443:443"
            - "8000:8000"
        links:
            - mysql
```

The reason why I think the problem is in the connection between the 2 containers is, because when i visit https://127.0.0.1/ I get 0 issues, however, as soon as I try to log in as the superuser, I get the error message **504 Timed-out**, so I assume the issue must be in the database. In the Dockerfile of the Django app I install only Mysql-Python and libmysqlclient-dev, should I install anything else in the container of the django application or is this enough? Another question that I have is, what is the difference between the image mysql-server and mysql on the dockerhub as their descriptions are exactly the same?

Comment: If there is an error between the connection of the DB and Django, django won't even initialize.

Comment: Well, in the very beginning I thought the same, so I did not even think the issue would be in the database (mysql), but in nginx, however, I decided to change the username in the `settings.py` just to see what error I would get. Eventhough the username in `settings.py` and `docker-compose.yml` did not match, it made no difference, so I am guessing the django container is not using the mysql database properly.

Comment: Don't you need to expose the MySQL port?

Comment: Well, I tried exposing it in the mysql part of the `docker-compose.yml`, yet no luck.

Comment: Can it be that docker-compose.yml is not the best choice when it comes to production, because the connection between the 2 containers is not as good as it should be and nginx is timing it out?